# How to join two tables in Django ORM without any column in first table referencing the second

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-models

Check the models below

Now I want to join the tables and get product name and price

I cannot join the tables as I have no column in Product model referencing Price model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Price(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: Why exactly do you add a `Price` model here, especially since your `price` field is just a reference to the `Product` model? If a product has multiple prices, the relation should probably be named `product = ...`, and you should add a `price = ...` column (with the price of that product, for example in a specific country)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem my bad, It was     product = models.ForeignKey(Product), Price = models.IntegerField()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`.select_related(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) on the `Price` model, like:

```
prices = Price.objects.select_related('product')
```

Then you can for example iterate over it, and print the product name together with the price, like:

```
for price in prices:
    print('{}: {}'.format(price.product.name, price.price))
```

or you can use [**`.annotate(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to take fields from a related model, like:

```
from django.db.models import F

products = Product.objects.annotate(price=F('price__price'))
```

and then print it with:

```
for product in products:
    print('{}: {}'.format(product.name, product.price))
```

Finally you can [**`.prefetch_related(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) the `Price`s, and then iterate over these, like:

```
products = Product.objects.prefetch_related('price_set')

for product in products:
    prices = product.price_set.all()
    if prices:
        for price in prices:
            print('{}: {}'.format(product.name, price.price))
    else:
        print('No prices for {}'.format(product.name))
```

That being said, if the price does not change in time, by country, etc. then it might be better to store the price in the `Product`.

Comment: I tried this as well. But the problem with this approach is that it will give details of products only which have Price details. What if I want all the products and empty price if it doesnt has Price

Comment: @Peekay: then you can use the latter, since then `price` will be `None`.

Comment: @Peekay: or you can iterate over the `.price_set`, but then it is performancewise better to use `.prefetch_related`.